# Laravel deploy to production and mix variable in env file issue

Tags: laravel, production-environment

Hi I am pretty new to Dev Ops side of things. So I have a Laravel Vue app where I utilize APIs for some request. Both web app and APIs are on same server for now.

So in my local env file I have variable like

MIX_DEFAULT_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

but in production env I have production URL

Problem is every time  I push to production the links are overriden and I have to run

npm run production to fix that

is there any solution to this or this is the way it is ?

Comment: Does your .env file gitignored ?

Comment: Yes it is.. I have different env on production

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Yes, you need to run it against the current .env as the variables are included in the output.

You could, however, make use of a [Mix extension](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/env-file) to specify which .env file to use. In your case, you would need to create a `.env.production` file and have it reference that by way of updating your `production` script in `package.json` to:

```
{
  "production": "NODE_ENV=production ENV_FILE=./.env.production ..."
}
```

(truncated for brevity)

Then, when running the build locally, `MIX_DEFAULT_API_URL` will be your production URL, or whatever you use in the production env.